# MySQL auto-increment set to 22378; new record assigned id = 1

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, eclipselink

MySQL (InnoDB) auto-increment seems to be properly configured, but calling

```
em.persist(entry)
```

results in the error:

Exception [EclipseLink 4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services 2.5.0.v20130507 3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException

Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062

The entity to be persisted (Entry), uses the primary key entry_id, by which it is joined to the inventory table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entries")
public class Entry implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8144553107778486945L;

/*
 * PRIMARY KEY & ID FOR THE CASE
 */
@Id
@Column(name="ENTRY_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)        // was TABLE
    private Long entry_id;

@Version
private Integer version;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "entry",
        cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name="entry_id")
private List<InventoryEntry> inventory =
    new ArrayList<InventoryEntry>();
```

Running the query:

```
select max(entry_id) FROM entries
```

yields:

```
max(entry_id)
22377
```

Running:

```
show table status from chambers like ‘entries’
```

in the MySQL Command Line Client shows the next auto-increment number to be:

```
22378
```

#### Question: why then is an id = 1 being assigned to a new record?

It is my understanding that auto-increment is reset on database start-up to max(id) + 1, and the query results confirm this is indeed the case.  I should add that this table formerly used: strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, and the Duplicate Entry '1' error first arose using this strategy (which is why I adopted the auto-increment strategy).  I have deleted the Sequence table.  I have also dropped the database and re-generated the schema from the Java classes, repopulating the data from a backup.  All to no avail.

Describe ENTRIES shows the configuration of the entry_id row as:

FIELD: ENTRY_ID,
TYPE: bigint(20), 
NULL: NO,
KEY: PRI,
DEFAULT: NULL,
EXTRA:  auto_increment

The row is indexed as PRIMARY.  Thus, everything appears to be in order.

I should add that this web application utilizes a MySQL InnoDB database running in a Glassfish 4.0 community server (recently upgraded from a Glassfish 3.1.2.2 embedded server).  Eclipse Kepler is the IDE on a Windows 7 64-bit platform.

I have exhausted the limits of my meager abilities.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your insert string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're seeing this problem because MySQL isn't generating the ID for the row, EclipseLink is. You can try using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` to force JPA to use an identity column (which forces a reread from the database to update the Java object), or you can restore the previous state; I don't know how EclipseLink implements `GenerationType.AUTO`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I'm still learning how to use annotations.

Comment: @RobertPeake You didn't do anything wrong with the annotation, it's just that what the annotation means (telling the JPA provider how to create the value) didn't match with what you wanted to happen (telling it to use the database's auto-assignment).

Comment: Auto defaults to table generation in EclipseLink.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` instead of `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`

**Because:**

The IDENTITY strategy also generates an automatic value during commit for every new entity object. The difference is that a separate identity generator is managed per type hierarchy, so generated values are unique only per type hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks to you and @chrylis for you quick response!  The solution works like a charm.